# Contador si encontró elemento en simple HTML DOM

Tags: php

Necesito hacer un contador para luego usarlo en un `for` pero las dos opciones que probé no funcionan.

```
 for ($i = 0; $i <= 16; $i++) {
$html =  file_get_html('https://m.web.com/');

$href1 = array();
foreach($html->find('a.b_match_all-link') as $element) {
  array_push($href1, $element->href );
  $cont=$cont+1;

}
// if ($href1==true){
//   $cont=$cont+1;
// }

// echo $href1[23];
$html2 =  file_get_html($href1[$i]);
```

La idea es que si hay un elemento `'a.b_match_all-link'` sume en el contador.
Previamente tengo un for de 0 al total del contador.

Comment: Qué problema estás teniendo exactamente?

Comment: Que no funciona. La idea es que si encuentra el elemento `'a.b_match_all-link'` sume en la variable `$cont` para luego usarlo en un `for`

Comment: Comprendo, pero cómo sabes que no funciona? qué muestra $cont? recorre el foreach? necesitamos toda la info para poder ayudarte

Comment: Ahi edité el tema para que te des una idea, puse que recorra `i de 0 hasta 16` pero la idea es que recorra hasta el contador.

Comment: Estás haciendo el for antes de obtener los elementos y, al menos en ese código, no se ve dónde estás inicializando el contador.

Comment: Ya se. el contador obviamente lo inicio arriba... Ahora estoy mirando de hacerlo con un while, pero me encuentro con el mismo problema

Comment: Hola, qué hace el método find?

Comment: Busca el elemento que está entre comillas simples si no me equivoco